# Run a proc on several different values of one parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query that gets run within a proc.  The function MyFunction returns a table, and this query joins on that table.  This proc works great when a @MyArg value is supplied.  However, I’m wondering if there’s a way to run this on all @MyArg values in the database.  I’m sure there’s a way to do it within a loop, but I know that loops are generally to be avoided at the db layer.

I really just need to perform this for the sake of checking (and possibly cleansing) some bad data.

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
FROM
(       
    SELECT 
        a.ColumnA, 
        a.ColumnB, 
        a.ColumnC,
        ROW_NUMBER() 
            over(partition by a.ColumnD order by f.ColumnX) as RowNum
    FROM dbo.MyTableA AS a
        INNER JOIN dbo.MyFunction(@MyArg) f ON f.myID = a.myID
    WHERE (a.myBit = 1 OR a.myID = @MyArg)
) AS x
WHERE x.rownum = 1;
```

Comment: if you did not supply @MyArg value what happens??

Comment: Could you provide the function??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if @MyArg= 0
select @MyArg =null

  SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
  FROM
  (       
  SELECT 
    a.ColumnA, 
    a.ColumnB, 
    a.ColumnC,
    ROW_NUMBER() 
        over(partition by a.ColumnD order by f.ColumnX) as RowNum
FROM dbo.MyTableA AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.MyFunction(@MyArg) f ON f.myID = a.myID
WHERE (a.myBit = 1 OR a.myID = @MyArg)
 ) AS x
  WHERE x.rownum = 1;
```

in your function add

```
 WHERE
(args.MyArg=COALESCE(@MyArg,  args.MyArg) or (@MyArg is null))
```

this will search all MyArgs values in the table

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use cross apply

```
with args as
(
  select distinct myarg
  from tbl
)

select f.*
from args
cross apply dbo.myfunction(myarg) f
```